# Convert separate node.js Buffers into array of buffer

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, buffer

I have 2 node.js buffers.

```
<Buffer 71 05 17 22>
<Buffer 88 02 fd ac>
```

I want to convert it to an array of buffer that will looks like this;

```
ArrayBuf = [<Buffer 71 05 17 22>, <Buffer 88 02 fd ac>]
```

This is so that I can access each buffer with something like `ArrayBuf[0]` and `ArrayBuf[1]`. Each individual element can be accessed with something like `ArrayBuf[0][1]`

I am using node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an array of buffers:

```
var b1 = new Buffer([0x71, 0x05, 0x17, 0x22]);
var b2 = new Buffer([0x88, 0x02, 0xfd, 0xac]);

var arrayBuf = [b1, b2];
```

Buffer's elements can be accessible via brackets notation, the same as in the arrays:

```
console.log(arrayBuf[1][2]); // will print '253', it's decimal value of '0xfd'
```